# What does "--" used in Excel function mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I came across this reference in a spreadsheet I'm looking at and don't understand what it means.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT((ISBLANK(CONSTRUCT))))
```

Can anyone tell me what the `--` in front of `NOT` refers to?

Comment: Interesting hack. Looks like its sole purpose is to convert TRUE/FALSE into 1/0. https://www.google.com/search?&q=excel%20double%20minus

Answer (score 3):

All the `--` does is tell Excel to convert the boolean search results to `0` or `1`.

> Anytime you need to use some type of logical function in Excel and
>   wish to have the results returned as either “1” or “0” instead of
>   “TRUE” or “FALSE,” simply use double minus signs as part of your
>   formula and you will be well on your way to creating some powerful
>   Excel formulas.

[image]

This [source](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/143-using-two-minus-signs-in-excel)  does a great job of explaining how to use this feature.

Comment: Source is first result of my Google search. Nice. ;-)