# Excel: Finding text within text without finding longer text (superstring)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Yesterday, I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1625315/excel-table-column-reference-by-referencing-second-table), the answer to which helped me in my quest to build a use case/role analysis table.  The answer propelled me forward, only to encounter a new hurdle.

I have a **Use Case** table that contains a bunch of information.  Roles are entered in a column, **User Persona**, comma separated, with a sample value being `BU Field, NBU Field, Contractor Field`.  Individual columns for the roles have formulas that look to see if that role (or "All") is found in the **User Persona** column for that particular use case, setting the value to `1` if it is and `0` if it isn't:

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(R$1,$K2)),$K2="All"),1,0)`

The trouble is that if the `FIND()` is looking for `BU Field` in `K2` and the value there is `NBU Field`, then it's going to find it.  I thought about searching for  `BU Field` (with a leading space), but that doesn't take into account values that start with `BU Field`.  I don't understand how the `ISNUMBER` function works here (Googled to find example, implemented it as-is), so can't really pick it apart to use something like `LEFT()` to arrive at a correct solution.

This is what I have now:

|  | K | R | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User Persona | BU Field | NBU Field |
| 2 | BU Field | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | NBU Field | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | BU Field, NBU Field | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | All | 1 | 1 |

<sup>[[Link to screenshot image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QygXK.png)</sup>

I want to get `R3` equal to `0`,
because `K3` doesn't contain `BU Field`, *per se*. 
How do I go about finding `BU Field` in a string that may or may not include `NBU Field` without returning a false positive?

Ideally I (or other users in the future) should be able to add new roles
simply by entering them into Row 1 and Column K,
without needing to change the formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with *I thought about searching for  `BU Field`*

You just need to add a space at the beginning and end of your search string, and also replace the commas with a `space`:

```
=--IFERROR(--(FIND(" " & G$1 & " "," " & SUBSTITUTE($F2,","," ") & " "))>0,$F2="ALL")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To search for "BU Field" but excluding hits within "NBU Field" do some string preprozessing:

Replace "NBU Field" by "" and search for "BU Field" afterwards. This way you can't get false positives.

14.2.2021 1:07 CET reacting to comment:

Assuming the text being in K1 we filter the part string "NBU Field" by replacing it with "":
L1=substitute(K1;"NBU Field";"")

If you then apply the find function to L1 all sources of wrong positives have been deleted. You may chain up both function if you like.

Comment: If I was writing software in C#, I would know how to do that.  I don't know how to do it in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This is your working formula

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(R$1,$K2)),$K2="All"),1,0)`

let's break it down

`=IF(TEST,1,0)`

You're testing a condition and returning a `1` if true and a `0` if not true.

You're using `OR`, so there are two distinct ways to satisfy your test, separated by commas. The first one:

`FIND(R$1,$K2)`

says 'look for the string in R1 inside the string in K2 and give me its position.' `FIND` returns an integer or an error. Therefore,

`ISNUMBER(FIND(R$1,$K2))`

is a boolean test of whether the search string is inside the search string; if it's not found, `FIND` returns an error and `ISNUMBER` is false.

Second test:

`$K2="All"`

Simple enough.

So if the field header is found inside the 'User Persona', or the 'User Persona' is "All", you get a 1 in your cell.

That gives us this:

[image]

@r2d3 gave you the beginning of a good idea but you asked for more detail. Here's how I'd do it:

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(SUBSTITUTE(R$1,"NBU","nonduplicated string"),SUBSTITUTE($K2,"NBU","nonduplicated string"))),$K2="All"),1,0)`

Of the pair of duplicative strings, take the longer one (which is inclusive of the other one) and use `SUBSTITUTE` to change it to something non duplicative in both terms of the `FIND` function.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether “cat” is present in “bird,fox,cat”
without finding it in “infield,pitcher,catcher” is a common problem. 
The common solution is to add “**,**” (a comma) to the beginning
and end of both strings: “**,**cat**,**”
(and “**,**bird**,**” and “**,**dog**,**”)
are present in “**,**bird,fox,cat**,**”
but not “**,**infield,pitcher,catcher**,**”. 
In your case we have to use “**,** ” (comma + space)
because that’s your delimiter.

So your formula becomes

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&R$1&", ", ", "&$K2&", ")), $K2="All"), 1, 0)
```

As [Ron demonstrates](https://superuser.com/a/1625639/150988) without discussion, if you’re trying to get
a `1` or `0` value out of a `TRUE` or `FALSE` scenario,
you don’t need to use

```
IF(logical value, 1, 0)
```

you can use

```
--logical value
```

see
[What does “--” used in an Excel function mean?](https://superuser.com/q/808815/150988) 
So the formula can be shortened to

```
=--OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&R$1&", ", ", "&$K2&", ")), $K2="All")
```