# Count from multiple columns with multiple conditions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have data that is arranged like

|  | (C) | (D) | (E) | (F) | (G) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | High; Average | High; Low | Low | 1.1, 1.2 | 2.4, 5.6 |
| 5 | High; Low | Low | Average | 1.1.2, | 1.1, 1.3 |
| 6 |  | Average; Low |  | 2.4, 1.2.3 | 1.2, 5.6 |
| 7 | High; | High | Average | 1.1, 1.2 | 3.4, 4.5 |

I need to count, say, how many times "High", "Average" and "Low" occur in front of "1.1" (for all rows) and then do the same for all numbers. Arrange the result in a table like this one (I have headers of this table sorted already. Need help with the count).

|  | High | Average | Low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1.1** | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| **1.2** | **⋱** |  |  |
| **1.3** |  | **⋱** |  |
| **2.4** |  |  | **⋱** |
| ︙ |  |  |  |
| ︙ |  |  |  |

The counts in the example are done manually. The dimensions of actual table are 200×8. I have tried `countifs(C4:E7, "*High*", F4:G7, "1.2")`. 
It gives an error. If I combine both parts of data into one column each respectively, it does not give required result. I cannot use `*1.2*` because there is `1.2.3` as well in the data.

One more attempt:
Using `countif` on the rows I have created this table:

|  | (I) | (J) | (K) | (L) | (M) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | **High** | **Low** | **Average** |  |  |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1.1, 1.2 | 2.4, 5.6 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1.1.2, | 1.1, 1.3 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2.4, 1.2.3 | 1.2, 5.6 |
| 7 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1.1, 1.2 | 3.4, 4.5 |

and then gave the formula `sumif(L4:M7, "*1.2*", I4:I7)`. 
It gives count of `6`. I don't understand this. It gives zero if use `"1.2"`. Ideally I would like any formula to take the condition `"1.2"` as a cell reference from Target table, e.g., `C12`.

Comment: Your data table is badly designed, but with a few helper columns you might be able to get to your end table with your sumif. The helper columns would be how many high, average and low you have in each row (get that with a combination of LEN, SUBSTITUTE, and CONCAT), as well as a helper column for your numeric data (e.g., 1.1, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surprisingly complicated. 
I hope somebody can find a good way to simplify my answer.

First of all, let me state some assumptions. 
Let’s describe the data table as being dimensioned (*n*+*m*)×*l*
— *n* columns in a group, followed by a group of *m* columns,
all extending vertically for *l* rows. 
So, for example, the table in the question is (3+2)×4. 
The cells in the first *n* columns contain lists of strings
(such as “High”, “Average” and “Low”, and possibly others)
separated by “;␣” (where “␣” represents a space). 
Let’s call these strings “words”. 
The cells in the remaining *m* columns contain lists of strings
(such as “1.1”, “1.2”, “3.4”, “5.6”, “1.2.3”, and probably many others)
separated by “,␣”. 
Let’s call these strings “numbers”.

There will never be a “High”, “Average”, “Low”, or any other word,
or a semicolon (‘;’), in the right-most *m* columns,
nor will there be a numeric value or a comma (‘,’)
in the left-most *n* columns. 
A cell may include a single value,
and it may end with the appropriate separator character for that column. 
A cell will not contain the same value multiple times
(e.g., “1.1, 1.2, 1.1”), or at least if it does, it counts only once.

The question is how to count all pairs of a given word and a given number
in the same row. 
A value (i.e., a cell) may count toward multiple pairs. 
For example,
the word “High” and the number “1.1” occur together six (6) times
just in this row:

|  | (C) | (D) | (E) | (F) | (G) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **High** | **High**; World | Waffle; **High** | **1.1**, 6, 8 | 42, **1.1** |

because we count C+F, C+G, D+F, D+G, E+F and E+G as six distinct pairs. 
We then need to add the counts for all the rows.

Creating a (deduped) list of *all* the words and numbers
is not part of the question; the OP has handled this.

---

`COUNTIFS` does seem to be an appropriate tool to use. 
And, since the cells contain lists of values,
it is appropriate to use patterns like `*High*`.

To paraphrase [my answer](https://superuser.com/q/1625590/150988#1625695) to [Excel: Finding text within text
without finding longer text (superstring)](https://superuser.com/q/1625590/150988):

> Checking whether “1.2” is present in “1.0,1.1,**1.2**”
> without finding it in “6.8,42,**1.2.3**” is a common problem. 
> The common solution is to add “**,**” (a comma) to the beginning
> and end of both strings: “**,**1.2**,**”
> (and “**,**1.0**,**” and “**,**1.1**,**”)
> are present in “**,**1.0,1.1,1.2**,**”
> but not “**,**6.8,42,1.2.3**,**”. 
> In your case we have to use “**,** ” (comma + space),
> because that’s your delimiter.

In that question, using `FIND()`,
it was possible to do this prepending and appending in place. 
That doesn’t seem to be possible in this case. 
My solution is to make a copy of the data, with the added delimiters. 
Specifically, I put it onto Sheet2. 
For your (3+2)×4 table starting in `C4` (on Sheet1), enter (on Sheet2):

- `C4` → `="; " & Sheet1!C4 & ";"`
- `D4` → `="; " & Sheet1!D4 & ";"`
- `E4` → `="; " & Sheet1!E4 & ";"`
- `F4` → `=", " & Sheet1!F4 & ","`
- `G4` → `=", " & Sheet1!G4 & ","`

and drag/fill down to cover all your data (i.e., all 200 rows). 
Note that, in accordance with your data, `C`, `D` and `E` use semicolons,
while `F` and `G` use commas.

Now go to the results matrix that you already have (as shown in the question)
— I’ll assume that the upper-left corner is `H1` — and enter this in `I2`:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$C$4:$C$7, "*; " & I$1 & ";*", Sheet2!$F$4:$F$7, "*, " & $H2 & ",*")
+COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$C$4:$C$7, "*; " & I$1 & ";*", Sheet2!$G$4:$G$7, "*, " & $H2 & ",*")
+COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$D$4:$D$7, "*; " & I$1 & ";*", Sheet2!$F$4:$F$7, "*, " & $H2 & ",*")
+COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$D$4:$D$7, "*; " & I$1 & ";*", Sheet2!$G$4:$G$7, "*, " & $H2 & ",*")
+COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$E$4:$E$7, "*; " & I$1 & ";*", Sheet2!$F$4:$F$7, "*, " & $H2 & ",*")
+COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$E$4:$E$7, "*; " & I$1 & ";*", Sheet2!$G$4:$G$7, "*, " & $H2 & ",*")
```

adjusting as necessary for your data. 
(For example, replace `7`
with the row number of the bottom of your data table —
or just a very large number — to allow for expansion.)

I hope the logic is semi-obvious. 
The first line counts rows where Column `C`
matches `*;␣High;*` —
in other words, where the list of words includes `High` —
***and*** the list of numbers in Column `F` includes `1.1`. 
And then we check for the other five combinations
(C+G, D+F, D+G, E+F and E+G).

And then drag/fill to cover all your words (in Row `1`)
and all your numbers (in Column `H`).

[image: the results]

This may seem like a lot of typing, but it’s manageable. 
Start by entering

```
'+COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$C$4:$C$7, "*; " & I$1 & ";*", Sheet2!$F$4:$F$7, "*, " & $H2 & ",*")
```

replacing `F` with the first column in the second group
(and replacing `7` as mentioned above). 
Then make *m*−1 (additional) copies of that formula fragment
(starting at the `+`) and adjust the second column name appropriately. 
For example, above, I changed `F` to `G` in the second row. 
Then make *n*−1 (additional) copies of those *m* lines
(again, starting at the `+`) and adjust the first column name appropriately. 
For example, above, I changed `C` to `D` in the third and fourth rows,
and to `E` in the last two. 
Then go back and change the `'+` to `=`.

Comment: @MátéJuhász The question says “I have headers of this table sorted already. Need help with the count”.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is not really good dealing with data structured like your example.
As presented in the other answer, it's possible to write some complex formula, but it'll be extremely complicated if you try to apply it on real (bigger) data.

To work efficiently first step would be to transform your data. Available tools for that in Excel are VBA and Power Query.

I'm going to give you a solution with Power Query as it's more user friendly for me

1. Latest version of Excel is coming already with Power Query. For Excel 2010 you need to install it separately.
2. select your source data and click "from table / range" (it'll be in powerQuery tab for you)
   [image]
3. you need to perform there transformations: merge columns, split columns, replace values. Below you can find the whole code, just need to change column names.
   [image]
4. Once your data is ready, you can load it and build a pivot table with your desired output.
   [image]

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"category 1", type text}, {"category 2", type text}, {"category 3", type text}, {"value 1", type text}, {"value 2", type text}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Changed Type",{"category 1", "category 2", "category 3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Categories"),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"value 1", "value 2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Values"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns1", {{"Categories", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Categories"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Categories", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1", {{"Values", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Values"),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Values", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type2"," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Values"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value"," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Categories"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Value1", each ([Categories] <> "") and ([Values] <> ""))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```